# element.style display incorrect information

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a simple html and javascript code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>p { height: 100px;} </style>
        <script>
            window.onload = function(){
                var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
                alert("actual height is " + p.style.height);
            };
        </script>
        <title>JavaScript Tests</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            100px height p element
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when we run it actual height is equal to empty string.
Could you please explain why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `style` property is different from the actual style in CSS: It looks for the `style` attribute, so this:

```
<p style="height: 100px"></p>
<script>alert(document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].style.height);</script>
```

will be "100px".

To get its actual height, use [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM%3awindow.getComputedStyle).

```
<style> p { height: 100px; }</style>
<p></p>
<script>alert(getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0]).getPropertyValue("height"));</script>
```

Comment: Note that `getComputedStyle()` is not well-supported across all popular versions of IE.

Comment: Indeed. You can use `elem.currentStyle.height` instead in IE.

Answer (score 2):

The `style` property refers to style attributes set explicitly on the element, *not* styles inherited from CSS declarations.

For example, try this:

```
<p style="height: 100px;">
```

Then you will see a value.  See [this document](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html) for an approach that will combine all of the various pieces of style information together to retrieve the actual composite style of an element.